# Random Number showing pointnumber and "0"

Tags: java, random

In this app a random number between 0-5 appears when the button is clicked. 
The Problem is, that the number appears as a pointnumber instead of a "normal" number.
For example: 4.7920870175158825

The second Problem is, that sometimes a number with a 0 before the comma appears,
For example: 0.7518324225208361

How can I fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn;
    TextView tw;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw);



        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tw.setText("Random Number: " + Math.random()*5);




            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert the value to int: `(int) (Math.random() * 5)`

Comment: You can also try `Random rnd = new Random(); rnd.nextInt(5);`

Comment: why unaccepted after you accepted my result as correct?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Random` and its [`nextInt(n)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) to get a random integer between 0 and n-1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    Random random = new Random();

    int Low = 0;
    int High = 5;
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    tw.setText("Random Number: " + randomNumber);

    System.out.println("Your random number is: "+randomNumber);
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine, I only had to replace int low = 0 with int low = 1. :) Thank´s

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndNum = rnd.nextInt(5) + 1;
tw.setText("Random Number: " + rndNum);
```

Comment: I tried it, but everytime i click the Button only one of These numbers appear: 01,11,21,31,41.

Comment: sorry, I fixed my mistake.

Comment: would you mind to upvote it? I have only 1 reputation :( Thanks